# Basic create-react-app jest test explained

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Im relatively new to JS, and can't figure out what is going on in line 2 of the following template jest test in the latest create-react-app:

```
    test('renders learn react link', () => {
      const { getByText } = render(<App />);
      const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
      expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

Does render always return a function called getByText? Is this destructuring? Why is it used as a method on the third line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code example you are asking about is not part of Jest per se. The `render` function is provided by [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro), a popular tool for testing React components.

Yes, in line 2, destructuring is used to get the function `getByText`. The `render` function actually [returns an object containing a number of functions](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render-result) that let you inspect the virtual DOM nodes rendered by React.

[getByText](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytext) can be used search for all elements in the rendered virtual DOM that have a text node with text content matching the given regular expression.

In line 3 of your code example, this is used to check if the text “learn react” is contained anywhere in the virtual DOM rendered by the `<App />` component.

In line 4, the expect function provided by Jest is used to make an assertion about this text being in the document.

The method [toBeInTheDocument](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobeinthedocument) of Jest's expect function here is actually provided by another library that sits on top of React Testing Library, *jest-dom*.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is called "destructuring". It pulls out methods / properties from objects.

i.e.

```js
// some random object
const obj = {
  property1: 'somevalue',
  method1: () => "hello"
}

const {property1, method1 } = obj;
console.log(property1, method1());
```

It can be useful when trying you need to call a method or value frequently from an object and get annoyed by having to call it with the object notation (`obj.method()`) repeatedly.

In your example, you could rewrite that as

```js
test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const element = render( < App / > );
  const linkElement = el.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

and it would be functionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is because unable to find an element with the text: /learn react/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements.

So I did it this way:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storeConfig from './store/storeConfig';
import App from './App';

const store = storeConfig();

test('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, div);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you put into your storeConfig file?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storeConfig from './store/storeConfig';
import App from './App';

const store = storeConfig();

test('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, div);
});
```